# If $f(x,y) = g(nx+y)$, is $g$ differentiable given $f$ is?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a problem which requires the following as a (say) lemma.

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable. If $f(x,y) = g(nx+y)$, does it tell the following:

1. $g$ is differentiable?
2. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = n \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$?

**Attempt:**

I think I was able to do the second part (Check!). But it requires $g$ to be differentiable. I could not do this.

For the second part,

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{dg(nx+y)}{dx} = n \frac{dg(nx+y)}{d(nx+y)} = n \frac{dg(nx+y)}{dy} = n \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$$

Comment: Note that $g(z)=f(0,z)$ so  the differentiability of $g$ follows from that of $f$.

Comment: @lulu Right, thanks!

Comment: The second part in my opinion uses a weird notation (curious what the other users think), even if I think it is conceptually correct...

Comment: @Thomas Can you point it out please? Is it the question or the proof I wrote? (Additionally, can you write the better version?)

Comment: The proof. In the second step you have  a total derivative of g w.r.t. something that is not the argument of g (apparently). So there I think you should keep the partial derivative. Than also the third step with the derivative w.r.t. nx+y looks weird to me formally

Comment: I mean each step has a well defined and correct meaning so I think it is conceptually correct, but I am not used to this writing. If I have time during the we I will write an answer using the notation I understand better...

Comment: @Thomas It did to me as well. But I couldn't think of a different way. And sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $g(y) = f(0,y)$ so $g$ is differentiable if $f$ is and the derivative of $g$ is equal to the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its second variable.

Comment: Can you add a proof please? I am looking for a proof.

Comment: I added a reference.

Comment: Doesn't that say that if $g$ and $h = nx+y$ are differentiable, then $f$ is also differentiable? In my case, $f$ and $h$ are differentiable and I need to know if that implies $g$ is differentiable.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Hopefully my answer is correct now.

Comment: No problem (and I have balanced the voting!)